# Download php genereted csv file though jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, download, export-to-csv

I can download a csv file from php, but I need to do it via jquery/javascript.

what would be the best solution for that? how to do it?

- Save php generated csv file in tmp dir and download via jquery/JS but how?(app used internally)
- Send array of data back to frontend, do all in jquery/JS.

Actually I want to update data on page and same time download changed rows!
I can not use any plug-in of any kind.

EDIT:
Ok! HERE is the full problem, i forget to mention.

I have a page with some rows from DB,

- I wanted to update selected rows in DB
- Same time get changed values and update rows on page
- download changed rows in csv

In one button click,

I cant use different buttons to save data and download file because after updating rows in db how would I get last updated rows?
With my limited knowledge, I can just get json response and update page Or download file not both!

Comment: Use an AJAX call to get the data for displaying on the page, and open the same URL in an iframe to trigger file download (since you said you can already download the file then I assume that means you've set the header correctly to trigger a download, rather than an open.)

Comment: if you want it for data only...convert to JSON using php library...is simpler working with JSON...make AJAX call from browser to retrieve data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is how i solved it :)

I made csv string out of json returned data in JS.
and used data URI scheme like here:
I made a link and that downloads .csv file.

```
var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_ouput);
$('#csv-btn-div').append('<a href="' + uri + '"download="csv-export.csv">Download CSV</a>');
```

There is another [solution](http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/11/download-json-to-csv-using-javascript/), if you want file save dialog to appear!

Thanks All!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("/someCsv.php", function(data) {
  // do stuff here.
});
```

Make sure to use some form of caching at the server side.

I would prefer preprocessed data (json):

```
$.get("/createJson.php", function(data) {
  // do stuff here.
});
```

Comment: I am geting my JSONed data here but how to make it download csv from within $.get

Comment: Use $.get() again, for the csv file location?