# Ajax Wont Download My CSV file ... Just returns comma delimited String

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I am passing some data to a controller action for our in house built framework, the way we do ajax calls is just a wrapper for regular ajax calls in Jquery.

```
CT.postSynch('report/payRollReport/createPayrollReport', {data : data}, function(data){});
```

The Data I am passing is two dates, which is used to create a csv file. This file would download normally IF I didn't have to select dates, that is if I hard code in the dates to select data between - the csv file will download.

How ever with above method, all I get back is a response that contains the coma delimited string, no file downloads. I am not sure why this is different: it downloads when its not an ajax call and it doesn't when it is an ajax call.

Obviously the headers are set right if it will download when its a regular link....

Any ideas on what I am should do with `data` if anything? to make it download the new file as opposed to spitting it out in a response object?

I then attempted to do the following:

```
    CT.postSynch('report/payRollReport/createPayrollReport', {data : data}, function(data){
        location.href='data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
    });
```

But what I am downloading is not a CSV its just a "download" as chrome calls is

Comment: performing an ajax call will not initiate a download. If you want it to be a download, don't use an ajax call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download CSV file using "AJAX"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346072/download-csv-file-using-ajax)

Comment: As a security feature, Javascript cannot create a file and give it to your web browser. You have to use an alternative way such as these posts suggest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771147/download-php-genereted-csv-file-though-jquery-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564103/using-javascript-to-download-file-as-a-csv-file

Comment: See the above OP it has been updated with an attempt @MonkeyZeus

Comment: @TheWebs thanks I just saw it after commenting

Comment: @MonkeyZeus So how would I get a file name and extension in there, by all accounts this should work .... it should download a csv file ...

Comment: The edit in the Accepted Answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side) seems to explain it

Comment: @MonkeyZeus is their any support for IE 8 ...... since IE lags behind them both .....

Comment: I have never implemented a file download via Javascript because of the downright inconsistencies between web browsers. My general procedure is usually to trigger a CSV creation process (myurl.com/createcsv.php) which creates the file on the server and returns an array containing True or False and and a filename (username.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').rand().microtime().csv) in JSON, then if creation was successful then have javascript redirect the user to another URL (myurl.com/getcsv.php?name=NameFromAjaxCall), once the getcsv script has finished executing then simply delete the file from the server.

Comment: were not saving the csv - they dont want to, they want and instant download.

Comment: I am confused, an instant download is a save.

Comment: How long does the `createPayrollReport` procedure usually take? If you set headers correctly in PHP then you can simply provide an `<a>` tag like this `<a href="report/payRollReport/createPayrollReport">Get Report</a>` and once the script finishes then the browser will actually stay on the same page and simply start the download process.

Comment: No most people save things to the server, like you generate a file its saved on the server, you go do something else, download the file later. this is generate the file, force the browser to download - also - not, you need date passed in via ajax.

Comment: I think you might be confusing technologies and protocols in terms of their intended purpose. What wrong with `<a href="report/payRollReport/createPayrollReport?start=2013-11-15&end=2013-11-18">Get report</a>`?